# Re-using a specific iexpore window by updating its URL

Tags: c#

I have an application that monitors a file, and based on its contents launches a browser using this code:

```
Process.Start("iexplore", "-nomerge " + fullUrl);
```

Now as with many small projects, the requirements have changed.  The change is that only one browser can be launched from my program at a time.

Also, another program is capable of launching a browser with another url, and I cannot shut it down, eliminating the option of just closing down all instances of iexplore and then launching mine. ( which is what I did originally )

Is there a way to launch a browser and continue to keep control of it so you can update the URL of that specific instance of iexplore using c#?

This code is close to what is in the answer on the duplicate post, but is slightly different, so I am sharing it here.

```
                       foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass())
                        {
                            if (ie.FullName.ToLower().Contains("iexplore") &
                                ie.LocationURL.ToLower().Contains("&qtype=mine"))
                            {
                                ie.Visible = true;
                                ie.Navigate(fullUrl);
                                openNewBrowserWindowWindow = false;
                            }
                        }

                        if (openNewBrowserWindowWindow) { 
                            SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass();
                            IE.Visible = true;
                            IE.Navigate(fullUrl);
                        }
```

Comment: Users tend to assume, once a browser window has been launched, that they can do anything they like with it - including browsing to other sites, etc. What you're planning sounds quite user hostile.

Comment: My intentions are nothing more that to serve the needs of the business I work for. I am only interested in controlling the url of a single iexplore instance, not all of them.

Comment: Have you considered using the web browser control in your app (or creating one using it)? That way you'd have full control over the URL, and you could prevent your users from re-using the browser window.

Comment: I have not considered that unit this post was marked as a potential duplicate.  Sadly, the question that I might have duplicated is unanswered,  but does have a snippet of code I think may do what I need. @beercohol